# Globally altering styles

Tags: preamble

Is there a generally applicable technique which will, for any tag/environment used in a LaTeX document, allow the default styling of the contents of instances of that tag/environment to be tweaked in the preamble?

- For instance, if I decided that all instances of `\emph{}` in the document should have their contents rendered not only italicised (a common default) but also bold, then what would I do?
- Similarly, if I decided that all instances of `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}` should have their contents rendered not only in a monospaced font (a common default) but also on a grey background, then what would I do?

But more importantly than simply explaining how to handle these two example cases, please can you outline a procedure a LaTeX user can follow in *all* cases in order to be able to change the styling of any given tag/environment.

Comment: These are really very different questions. There is *no* procedure that can work in all cases.

Comment: Ideally, I'd  be after something that works like using the `<style>` element in the `<head>` section of an HTML document. This would be a generally applicable single-step solution. However, if there is no generally applicable single-step solution, that does not mean there is no generally applicable solution. How, @egreg (and others reading this), if you did not know how to style a tag/environment, would you approach the problem of **first** finding out how to style it and **second** styling it using the preamble or some other document-wide mechanism?

Comment: Just one example: `\section` has to do *much* more than a `<head>` tag in HTML, where, for instance, there's no problem with page breaking, widows and orphans. Comparing (La)TeX and HTML is really wrong.

Comment: I don't see any similarity between `\section` in LaTeX and `<head>` in HTML. However, the preamble in LaTeX *is* comparable to `<head>` in HTML.

Comment: OK, wrong example. But still there is *no* similarity between LaTeX and HTML, other than both use a kind of markup.

Comment: That's a pretty big similarity! Anyhow, I provided the analogy merely in case it helped anyone here see what I was getting at, not for any other reason. If it didn't help you, that's a pity, but it may yet help someone else. My question still stands.

Comment: I guess the comparison is `\section` to `<h1>`. LaTeX wasn't designed to be easily stylable by *authors*. On the other hand ConTeXt is (as far as I know – I never really used it) much easier to style in this way.

Comment: @egreg: In some sense one could argue that from a users point of view, LaTeX is similar to plain HTML 4 (without CSS (and hence `<style>`), JavaScript, etc.). Except of course that LaTeX automates many tasks (toc, ...).

Comment: @Caramdir, if not for authors, then for whom was LaTeX designed to be easily styled?

Comment: @sampablokuper You're presuming that LaTeX was designed to be easily styled.  Probably better would be to assume that it was designed to be flexible.  The "ease", I guess, would be contained in whatever interface the package/macro writers are able to provide to the author. (I'm just a rookie, so take that with a grain of salt)

Comment: @ScottH. no, I was picking up on Caramdir's comment that "LaTeX wasn't designed to be easily stylable by *authors*", which begs the question.

Comment: @sampablokuper: Partially the idea is that users *should not* be able to alter styles easily. Getting good typography is not easy and (so the idea goes) something best left to the experts. If you want to do something different, you should use a corresponding class or package. (Also writing fully stylable macros in TeX isn't exactly easy...) Some document classes (KOMA, memoir) provide more flexibility.

Comment: @Caramdir, this does not make sense to me. Given that many publishers must want to accept LaTeX submissions *and* want their output to be typeset according to a distinctive house style rather than only according to the rules of a generic LaTeX preset, how do those publishers override/modify/etc LaTeX defaults in order to create their house styles?

Answer (score 3):

Let's tackle only the first example. LaTeX declares `\emph` with

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\em}
```

so we need to look up what `\em` does:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\em{%
  \@nomath\em
  \ifdim \fontdimen\@ne\font >\z@
    \upshape
  \else
    \itshape
  \fi}
```

The first instruction, `\@nomath\em` raises an error if the command is found in math mode, otherwise it does nothing. The conditional checks whether the current font is slanted (in this case `\fontdimen1\font` is positive); if so it issues `\upshape`, otherwise `\itshape`.

So, if you want `\emph` to choose "boldface italic" in an upright context and "upright boldface" in an italic context you have to say

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\em{%
  \@nomath\em
  \ifdim \fontdimen\@ne\font >\z@
    \upshape\bfseries
  \else
    \itshape\bfseries
  \fi}
```

Is this a general method? No.

I won't even think to the changes necessary to print verbatim material on a grey background: the `fancyvrb` package provides such a feature and its code is *very* complicated.

In LaTeX you can't simply hand calls to the browser like HTML does. The two models are completely different.

Comment: I'm grateful for this, but although it addresses one of my examples, it doesn't really answer my question. How did you establish what LaTeX declares `\emph` (or any other command) to be? Why was this your first step? How did you look up what `\em` (or any other command) does? Where should the third code snippet you gave be put in order to apply to all instances of `\emph` in the present document? These are the sorts of things my question is getting at.

Comment: @sampablokuper To look things up: `\show\emph` (etc.) in your document or `texdoc source2e`.

Answer (score 0):

As egreg says there is no general way -- each one needs to be considered separately. So for the `\emph` you could redefine the command in the preamble:

[image]

### Note:

- As egreg pointed out, this required the use of `\LetLtxMacro` macro from [the `letltxmacro` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) instead of `\let` since `\emph` is declared with `\DeclareRobustCommand`.
- As Caramdir  pointed out this may or may not be what is desired for nested use `\emph{}`. This redefinition yields an alternating bold italic, with bold upright, where as the original definition yields an alternating non-bold italic, with a non-bold upright as shown above.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro\OldEmph\emph
\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{\textbf{\OldEmph{#1}}}%

\begin{document}
    \OldEmph{orignal emph}\par
    \emph{modified emph}\par
    \emph{modified emph with a \emph{nested emph}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\emph` is basically defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand` and it's quite dangerous to redefine it in this way (see the documentation of `letltxmacro`.

Comment: @egreg, but if `letltxmacro` were used instead of `let` then this approach would generally be OK? Or would there still be a danger - and if there is still a danger, then what would it be?

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, I was mistaken in thinking that `\LetLtxMacro` was only required when there were optional parameters. Have updated the solution.

Comment: This of course might or might not do what you intend when nesting `\emph`s.