# How to simulate old typewriter?

Tags: memoir, typewriter

I need to typeset a report such that it looks like it was written by an old, unreliable typewriter.

I have looked into the `memoir` class, however it has chapter numbering which I don't want. It also looks too clean.

I have looked into the `manuscript` package, but it looks way too clean for what I want.

Digging around I found a `typewriter` package, but it is no longer on CTAN and even getting the .sty from the author's git I can't get it to work properly: probably because it requires compiling with lualatex which I have zero experience with.

Is there an available package that does what I want easily? Namely, that makes my document look like it was written with an old, unreliable typewriter.

Alternatively, is there a way to get the `typewriter` package to work?

Alternatively, even just editing the `memoir` class such that it behaves more like `article` would be acceptable.

Comment: Have you got a picture of the kind of look you're after?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344214/use-latex-to-simulate-old-typewriter-written-texts

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, the first answer to that question is the `typewriter` package I can't get to work. The look that answer achieves would be perfect.

Comment: the typewriter package there was never on ctan, what error did you get?

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't realize that you mean this. But Davids code works without problem for me.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer naturally!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Even if I run it in a terminal ;-)

Comment: in any case the question is clearly a duplicate (the older question could usefully have some non-luatex answers) but if anyone has such an answer it could be posted there

Comment: I'm on the train now, so all info is from my memory... That said, first I got the "requires lualatex" error, then running `lualatex myFile.tex` spews out a bunch of errors that I promptly ignored, runs successfully and returns a pdf consisting of two empty pages.

Comment: Also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-a-cthulhu-worshipping-madm?s=1|29.7304

Comment: Btw: You should never ignore a "bunch of errors"!

Comment: It gives me a `font \myfonts=such and such at x pt not loadable: metric data not fund or bad` followed by `attempt to index global 'f' (a nil value)`, repeated 5 times for different fonts and sizes. I can dump the terminal output on pastebin, if you want.

Comment: Fixed. I was just missing `cmuntt.otf`. Now it works almost perfectly, except `\maketitle` appears to also produce an empty page at the beginning. I had to encase it in a `{\let \newpage \relax ...}` block.

Comment: If you want `memoir` to emulate `article` then `\documentclass[...,article]{memoir}` (read the manual) or just to stop chapter numbering (and below) put `\setsecnumdepth{part}` in your preamble.

Comment: @David Carlisle You,and others,  have declared this to be a duplicate question but I disagree and how can I do that officially?  The questioner asked about old typewriter output which already had an answer but he also asked about changing `memoir` as a solution which I answered in my comment. I understand that it's difficult if more than one problem/solution is suggested in a question.

Comment: @PeterWilson just vote to re-open, if 5 people vote then it opens. I'll vote as well so that's 2 although it would be better if the question (and especially the title) were edited to make it not a duplicate, the title is an almost exact duplicate currently.

Comment: @PeterWilson Or you can raise on meta making the case. David altered me in chat, so I've used mod powers to reopen without a need for voting :)

Comment: Also related, possibly: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122970/simulate-printing-imperfections-and-defects-with-tex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the questions about `memoir`: if you don't want chapters numbered then put `setsecnumdepth{part}` in your preamble or, for all classes with `\chapter` use `\chapter*` to have an unnumbered title.

To make `memoir` output similar to that of the `article` class use the `article` option:

```
\documentclass[...,article]{memoir}
```

With this option `\chapter` behaves as `\section`, `\section` as `\subsection` and so on. This ability was introduced to help those (many) authors (or their supervisors) who could not decide between `report` or `book` class type output and an `article` style document without having to do extensive rewrites.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it is the most pertinent to my original point, even though I managed to make David's code work and ultimately settled on that solution.

Answer (score 16):

[image: bad typewriter]

I've generated a lookup table of macros to print characters with a vertical offset that's random but consistent for each character.  This covers all printable ascii characters except those that have to be escaped in LaTeX.

A few letters are used as examples of special cases for how the characters can be further modified:

- `T` has a 50% chance of a double hit (with the underneath hit in grey).
- `e` is so worn it's fake bold.
- `t` has a bent arm, tilting it to the right
- `w` has a wobbly arm resulting in a random tilt to the left

A similar approach could be used to make compound symbols (like `{'\hspace{-0.5em}.}` instead of `!`, but this doesn't work very well in `cmtt`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{cmtt}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmtt}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[first=0, last=10,counter=rnd]{lcg}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{ulem}
\newlength{\charwidth}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\BTsetupchar}[3]{\csdef{BT#1}{{\raisebox{#2 pt}{#3}}}}
\newcommand{\BTchar}[1]{\ifcsdef{BT\expandafter#1}{\csuse{BT#1}}{#1}}
\def\BTtype#1{%
    \@BTtype#1 \@empty
}
\def\@BTtype#1 #2{%
   \zz{#1}\space  
   \ifx #2\@empty\else
    \expandafter\@BTtype
   \fi
   #2%
}
\def\zz#1{\def\zzsep{}\zzz#1\relax}
\def\zzz#1{\ifx\relax#1\else\BTchar{#1}\expandafter\zzz\fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\rnddoublehit}[2]{%first arg is character, second is probability (expressed as 0...10 out of 10)
\rand%
\ifnum\value{rnd}<#2{%
    \settowidth{\charwidth}{#1}%
    \makebox[0 pt]{\textcolor{DarkGrey}{#1}\hspace{-0.9\charwidth}}%
}\fi%
#1%
}
\newcommand{\fakebold}[1]{%
\hspace{0.25em}\makebox[0pt]{#1}\hspace{-0.01em}\makebox[0pt]{#1}\raisebox{0.01em}{\makebox[0pt]{#1}{\hspace{-0.01em}\makebox[0pt]{#1}}}\hspace{0.25em}%
}

\newcommand{\randomrotate}[1]{%
\rand\turnbox{\value{rnd}}{#1}\phantom{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\fixedrotate}[2]{%
\turnbox{#2}{#1}\phantom{#1}%
}

\BTsetupchar{!}{0.959552631912}{!}
\BTsetupchar{"}{-0.572568292908}{"}
\BTsetupchar{'}{-0.42445901612}{'}
\BTsetupchar{(}{0.691721871811}{(}
\BTsetupchar{)}{0.446192095977}{)}
\BTsetupchar{*}{0.668289632872}{*}
\BTsetupchar{+}{0.21316900542}{+}
\BTsetupchar{,}{0.910994324343}{,}
\BTsetupchar{-}{-0.0643612216322}{-}
\BTsetupchar{.}{0.630916143844}{.}
\BTsetupchar{/}{-0.208079854503}{/}
\BTsetupchar{0}{-0.959606455046}{0}
\BTsetupchar{1}{-0.656692744652}{1}
\BTsetupchar{2}{0.715910870838}{2}
\BTsetupchar{3}{0.801503738677}{3}
\BTsetupchar{4}{-0.32605935154}{4}
\BTsetupchar{5}{-0.675172696056}{5}
\BTsetupchar{6}{0.751559563665}{6}
\BTsetupchar{7}{0.976916884466}{7}
\BTsetupchar{8}{-0.975884092147}{8}
\BTsetupchar{9}{-0.283530490249}{9}
\BTsetupchar{:}{0.883460953498}{:}
\BTsetupchar{;}{-0.157194078996}{;}
\BTsetupchar{<}{-0.856089720103}{<}
\BTsetupchar{=}{-0.462380899054}{=}
\BTsetupchar{>}{-0.127783763665}{>}
\BTsetupchar{?}{0.340250629436}{?}
\BTsetupchar{@}{0.0681232531923}{@}
\BTsetupchar{A}{-0.28199357967}{A}
\BTsetupchar{B}{-0.908136793624}{B}
\BTsetupchar{C}{0.876151420093}{C}
\BTsetupchar{D}{-0.562459892016}{D}
\BTsetupchar{E}{0.447753032908}{E}
\BTsetupchar{F}{0.949806536361}{F}
\BTsetupchar{G}{-0.83022989235}{G}
\BTsetupchar{H}{0.237512188109}{H}
\BTsetupchar{I}{0.97859690646}{I}
\BTsetupchar{J}{-0.403375721451}{J}
\BTsetupchar{K}{0.96981128078}{K}
\BTsetupchar{L}{0.796113416346}{L}
\BTsetupchar{M}{-0.366049268456}{M}
\BTsetupchar{N}{0.198166324344}{N}
\BTsetupchar{O}{-0.100789626885}{O}
\BTsetupchar{P}{-0.183992646309}{P}
\BTsetupchar{Q}{0.173168897111}{Q}
\BTsetupchar{R}{0.480851283624}{R}
\BTsetupchar{S}{-0.614801263924}{S}
\BTsetupchar{T}{0.232244730499}{\rnddoublehit{T}{5}}
\BTsetupchar{U}{-0.841735743114}{U}
\BTsetupchar{V}{0.331678931812}{V}
\BTsetupchar{W}{0.49613372548}{W}
\BTsetupchar{X}{0.845697981975}{X}
\BTsetupchar{Y}{-0.482183997158}{Y}
\BTsetupchar{Z}{0.193975227977}{Z}
\BTsetupchar{[}{0.537571176714}{[}
\BTsetupchar{]}{-0.158672666173}{]}
\BTsetupchar{`}{-0.88025147726}{`}
\BTsetupchar{a}{0.78692076979}{a}
\BTsetupchar{b}{0.649368560189}{b}
\BTsetupchar{c}{0.902390617527}{c}
\BTsetupchar{d}{0.531144863033}{d}
\BTsetupchar{e}{0.236409401365}{\fakebold{e}}
\BTsetupchar{f}{0.643224218751}{f}
\BTsetupchar{g}{-0.0139542454465}{g}
\BTsetupchar{h}{-0.147690280772}{h}
\BTsetupchar{i}{0.58033164118}{i}
\BTsetupchar{j}{-0.795721708264}{j}
\BTsetupchar{k}{0.0175291953771}{k}
\BTsetupchar{l}{0.148103630735}{l}
\BTsetupchar{m}{-0.0330127123047}{m}
\BTsetupchar{n}{0.965120551956}{n}
\BTsetupchar{o}{-0.782274884983}{o}
\BTsetupchar{p}{-0.912884787628}{p}
\BTsetupchar{q}{-0.737446301979}{q}
\BTsetupchar{r}{-0.035564484607}{r}
\BTsetupchar{s}{0.980692209771}{s}
\BTsetupchar{t}{-0.195345192206}{\fixedrotate{t}{-5}}
\BTsetupchar{u}{-0.900370841615}{u}
\BTsetupchar{v}{0.88405712738}{v}
\BTsetupchar{w}{-0.235893592391}{\randomrotate{w}}
\BTsetupchar{x}{0.529953305453}{x}
\BTsetupchar{y}{-0.494754361551}{y}
\BTsetupchar{z}{-0.861855138219}{z}
\BTsetupchar{|}{0.058513536895}{|}


\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\BTtype{This text was typed by a monkey on the world's worst typewriter.  This text was typed by a monkey on the world's worst typewriter.  This text was typed by a monkey on the world's worst typewriter.  This text was typed by a monkey on the world's worst typewriter.}

\emph{\BTtype{This text is underlined using the ulem package}}
\end{document}
```

The lookup table was generated using python:

```
import random
for i in range (33,127):
    c=chr(i)
    if not c in "&%$#_{}~^\\": 
        print "\BTsetupchar{"+c+"}{"+str((random.random()-0.5)*2)+"}{"+c+"}"
```

I haven't tried to handle maths mode or accented letters -- in fact any control sequence or escaped special character few to the macro breaks.  It is possible (as demonstrated) to emphasise the text, but the `\emph{}` must be on the outide.

A few more ideas:

- Implement underlining with a load of `\textunderscore`s
- Fake-bold one or more characters for emphasis
- Basic maths (using a handwriting font for characters not on the a standard typewriter would be a bonus)

Important sources:

- [Davids Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364545/28808) to *What's the best way to explode a string into characters, process each character individually, and join them back?*
- [Martin Scharrer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11598/28808) to *Iterate over space-separated list*

Comment: I've spotted a bug in `\rnddoublehit` -- the grey letter will always be a `T` (a hangover from how I demonstrated it) , and (similarly) the `\hspace` should depend on the character width even though this is constant in a typewriter font.

Comment: Awesome work. How do I make my whole document to use BTtype as a default font?